# How to create custom Select2 themes?

Tags: jquery-select2

Select2 [documentation mentions](https://select2.org/appearance#themes) support for custom themes using the `theme` option.

```
$(".js-example-theme-multiple").select2({
  theme: "classic"
});
```

I've searched the web and SO but can't find more information on the subject. I'd like to create my own theme for my site, call it `mySite` and apply it to Select2.
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom theme using as starting point the "default" theme that you could find included in `css/select2.css`:

1. Create a blank .css file and copy/paste in it all the rules having "--default" in their name
2. Replace the "--default" part of the name with "--mysite" and do your customizations
3. include in your page this new .css after the main select2 .css
4. now you can use the option `theme: "mysite"`